# Present and past perfect

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

I’ve got a problem with the choice of these tenses in my story,In my story I threw a party, which was about 2 weeks ago, and now I’m telling this story, so, which is correct for mentioning this verb in my story;

“I’d thrown a party..”
Or
“I’ve thrown a party..”
Thanks a lot

Comment: There have been _many_ questions on this topic. If you are simply telling the story from the point of view of _now_, say "I threw a party two weeks ago". If you are telling it from the point of view of some moment in the past - "I'd thrown a party two weeks before".

Comment: Thank you ever so much

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.